# @PreAuthorize makes validation not working for primitive type

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-validator

First of all, this is my development environent.

1. Spring boot: org.springframework.boot:2.5.6
2. io.spring.dependency-management: 1.0.11.RELEASE
3. Spring Security: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security
4. org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux
5. kotlin
6. org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation

When I call this api with invalid value of limit(as 100), validator(@Max) is working successfuly.

`Call: GET {{apiEndpoint}}/workspaces/{{workspaceId}}/test?limit=1000`

*Code*

```
    @GetMapping("/test")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    suspend fun test(
        auth: AuthToken,
        @PathVariable workspaceId: String,
        @RequestParam(name = "limit", defaultValue = "15") @Max(20) limit: Int
    ): String {
        return "OK"
    }
```

*Response*

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
requestId: 32511EB3433F4D1DBEAC56641E6BE1A2
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 213
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1 ; mode=block
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer

{
  "requestId": "32511EB3433F4D1DBEAC56641E6BE1A2",
  "message": "test.limit: 20 이하여야 합니다",
  "sys": {
    "id": "UnhandledError",
    "code": "50001",
    "type": "Error"
  },
  "details": {
    "exception": "ConstraintViolationException"
  }
}
```

But with @PreAutorize annotation, validator is not working.
*Code*

```
    @GetMapping("/test")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    suspend fun test(
        auth: AuthToken,
        @PathVariable workspaceId: String,
        @RequestParam(name = "limit", defaultValue = "15") @Max(20) limit: Int
    ): String {
        return "OK"
    }
```

*Response*

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
requestId: B0F832B0AACA49DDB2F5774FE3BFB8D4
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf8
Content-Length: 2
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1 ; mode=block
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer

OK
```

Why spring-security makes validator not working??
Plus, validator for Object(not primitive type) type is working successfuly with @PreAuthorize.

```
    @PostMapping("/test")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    suspend fun test(
        auth: AuthToken,
        @PathVariable workspaceId: String,
        @RequestBody @Valid body: Payload         // It works!!
    ): String {
        return "OK"
    }
    
    data class Payload(
        @field:Max(10)
        val age: Int
    )
```

Please help me.

I also tried to use `groups(ValidationGroups)', but it's not works too.

Comment: Can you try adding the `@Validated` annotation to your controller class?

Comment: All Controllers has `@Validated` annotation already. If I remove `@PreAuthorize` annotation, `@Max()` works successfully. I thinks `@PreAuthorize` makes argument validation does not work.

Comment: If `@PreAuthorize` is not exists, `org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor::invoke()` is called for validate paramters, but it exists that invoke method never called.

Comment: Can you create an issue within the Spring Security repository in GitHub with a link to a reproducible sample? This scenario might be a bug

Comment: https://github.com/und3rs/springboot-helpme

You can test with `\src\test\kotlin\test.http` after run the project.

Comment: The discussion is running in the Spring Security repository since it seems to be a bug https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10470

Comment: Thank you. I've just checked it out. :)